# .NET Core new SelectList returns null

Tags: asp.net-core

I am writing a .netcore webapp and I am using globalization to populate a list of countries  this is in my controller class:

```
public IActionResult GetCountry()
    {
        List<string> CountryList = new List<string>();
        CultureInfo[] cInfoList = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
        foreach (CultureInfo cInfo in cInfoList)
        {
            RegionInfo r = new RegionInfo(cInfo.LCID);
            if(!(CountryList.Contains(r.EnglishName)))
            {
                CountryList.Add(r.EnglishName);
            }
        }
        //sort list into order
        CountryList.Sort();
        ViewBag.CountryList = CountryList;
        return View(CountryList);
    }
```

I have the following in my model class:

```
[Display(Name ="Country of Origin")]
    public string GetCountry { get; set; }
```

and finally in my cshtml I have the following:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="GetCountry"></label>
            <select asp-for="GetCountry" asp-items="new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList)"></select>
            
        </div>
```

I am not sure where I have gone wrong but it will give me the following message during runtime.

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: items
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList..ctor(IEnumerable items, string dataValueField, string dataTextField, IEnumerable selectedValues, string dataGroupField)

I've probably done something silly but any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code that you are using, does correctly populate the list of cultures.

[image]

It's more than likely that your .cshtml file is not populated with the correct view model.

At the top of the page, you'd normally see something like:

```
@model MyApplication.Models.Country.CountryListModel;

ViewBag.CountryList = Model.CountryList;
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed `@` in `asp-items`

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="GetCountry"></label>
    <select asp-for="GetCountry" asp-items="@(new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList))"></select>
</div>
```

Comment: I added the @() but unfortunately I still have the same error